# How to import existing XML files as requests to SoapUI API in JAVA?

Tags: java, xml, soap, soapui, load-testing

1. I already have the XML requests for SOAP.
2. I want to import these XML files using SoapUI API in JAVA as requests to do loadtest.
3. Other than SoapUI, are there any other tools that provides similar API and easy to use? 
   ps: Loadtest is part of JAVA project, I have to do everything in JAVA.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: What is the difficulty you are facing to use soapui as it has all the functionality you are looking for and you could achieve this using soapui free edition. Any constraints that you have?

Comment: By the way, to send web service requests, take look at https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite, not used for load testing though. May be you need to hadle on your own.

Comment: @Avery 
1. I have some XML files there and can be read by SOAP server as request and get response back. 
2. I need to use java to import those XML requests and do the load test. I found SOAPUI has its api to use in JAVA but I found out it could only import the wsdl and you have to create your request. So I wanna find out a way to direct use my XML requests rather than convert those XML to SOAPUI request objects and then SOAPUI converts them to XML and send to SOAP server.

Comment: @Rao  I need to use java to call soapui api or some other similar tool to import XML requests to do loadtest. But I did not see soapui provides such api that can be used to import XML files as requests. I have to create  the soapui request objects.

Comment: Not sure why you want to reinvent the wheel. By the way how may requests do you have?

Comment: @Rao  I am working on a plugin for a huge project.

Comment: @Rao I have more than 1 thousand requests in record now and can be more.

Comment: In that case, you can use the library mentioned in the first comment to send web service request which allows you to send the request as it is.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have a list of requests that you simply want to throw at an endpoint automatically one after the other, looking for a successful or failed response.

In that case, this is working code from an automation project I did a few months ago.  Add your endpoint, SOAPAction header (if needed), and success criteria, feed the XML requests in one at a time through a looped function call, and you should be good to go.

```
// This method takes a string object representing the XML request we want to
// run, manipulates it
// to add our header and footer, sends the message to a SOA endpoint, waits
// for a response,
// parses the response, and then logs the response for later analysis
public static void sendRequest(String request) {
    try {
        // Create a SOAPConnection
        SOAPConnectionFactory factory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection connection = factory.createConnection();
        // This output stream is used for writing the contents of the SOAP
        // message and response for logging
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // This stringbuilder will hold the response message from SOA
        StringBuilder soapResp = new StringBuilder();
        // THis stringbuilder will hold the initial message we sent to SOA
        StringBuilder soapMsg = new StringBuilder();

        // This line calls the "getSoapMessageFromString" method and passes
        // it our header constant, the raw XML
        // request, and our footer constant to generate a SOAPMessage object
        SOAPMessage message = getSoapMessageFromString(EA_SOAP_ENV_HEADER
                + request + EA_SOAP_ENV_FOOTER);

        // Create an endpoint from the previoulsy selected string which is a
        // URL type object
        URL endpoint = new URL("endpoint");

        // Get the MIME headers from the message object we just created
        MimeHeaders headers = message.getMimeHeaders();
        // Add the SOAPAction header with a value of "establishActivity" to
        // the headers
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "yourAction");

        // Send a SOAPMessage (request) and then wait for SOAPMessage
        // (response)
        SOAPMessage response = connection.call(message, endpoint);

        // Write the initial message to the byte array output string
        message.writeTo(baos);
        // append the baos data (initial message) to the stringbuilder for
        // processing
        soapMsg.append(baos.toString());
        // Reset the baos for use on the response message
        baos.reset();

        // Write the response message to the byte array output string
        response.writeTo(baos);
        // append the baos data (response message) to the stringbuilder for
        // processing
        soapResp.append(baos.toString());
        // Reset the baos for use on the next message
        baos.reset();

        // If the response message does NOT contain the text
        // 'cmdStatus="OK"', then
        // send the initial request to the log formatted in large red bold
        // text and
        // also send the error response message to the log formatted in
        // normal red text
        if (soapResp.toString().indexOf("cmdStatus=\"OK\"") < 0) {
            sendToLog("<pre id=\"content\"><font size=\"5\" color=\"red\"><b>REQUEST:  "
                    + soapMsg.toString().trim().replaceAll("<", "&lt;")
                            .replaceAll(">", "&gt;")
                    + "</b></font></pre><p>");
            sendToLog("<pre id=\"content\"><font color=\"red\">ERROR MESSAGE:<P>"
                    + soapResp.toString().trim().replaceAll("<", "&lt;")
                            .replaceAll(">", "&gt;") + "</font></pre>");
        }
        // If the text 'cmdStatus="OK"' DOES exist in the response, then
        // simply add one to the successfully re-run count
        else {
            successCount++;
        }

        // Add one to the total count of records processed
        totalCount++;

        // Close the SOAPConnection
        connection.close();
        soapMsg.setLength(0);
        soapResp.setLength(0);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

// This method takes an XML string as input and uses it to create a new
// SOAPMessage object
// and then returns that object for further use.
private static SOAPMessage getSoapMessageFromString(String xml)
        throws SOAPException, IOException {

    MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();

    // Create a new message object with default MIME headers and the data
    // from the XML string we passed in
    SOAPMessage message = factory
            .createMessage(
                    new MimeHeaders(),
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(Charset
                            .forName("UTF-8"))));
    return message;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and help @roflplanes. This is extremely helpful to my project.

Comment: Did that answer your question @Grrrrrrrrrrrrrr?  If so, can you please mark the answer as correct and if not, can you please clarify what you're looking for so I can edit my answer to meet your requirements?